# JSON data from MySql to SQLite in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, sqlite

I have used PHP to generate a JSON data which parses data from MySQL to SQLite in Android which looks as follows:

```
{"tag":"login","success":1,"tables":[{"tname":"TeacherTB","tdata":[{"TeachID":"T1","TeachName":"ABC"}]},{"tname":"ClassTB","tdata":[{"ClassID":["C1","C2"],"ClassName":["PQR","XYZ"]}]}]  
}
```

TeacherTB, ClassTB are table names and TeachID,TeachName,ClassID,ClassName are database column names.
tname is table name and tdata is data in that table from the MySQL database.
I have the same name for tables and columns in both databases(MySql and SQLite).
I want to insert these data into sqlite database that i have created in android. How can i extract these data from JSON in android to do the insertions into the SQlite database? Thank you! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONbject`.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String tag = jsonObject.getString("tag");
int success = Integer.parse(jsonObject.getString("success"));
JSONArray tables = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tables");
...
```